# jQuery "Chosen" for Select Boxes - how to apply styling after AJAX loads the select element

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-chosen

So I'm trying to apply the [Chosen jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) to a select box after it has been loaded via [XAJAX](http://www.xajaxproject.org/).  Here's the code:

Normally, I start on page load, and all select boxes with the class are correctly styled appropriately:

```
$(document).ready( function () {        
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
});
```

Next, I have a function that uses XAJAX to display the new select box in the specified DIV on the page.  This works fine.  HOWEVER, it's not styled by Chosen as it should be.

I have tried to add a delay in there too, because I read on some forums that that worked for some people.  It does not work....

```
function getNewSelect(property_id){
    xajax_getNewSelect();
    $(".chzn-select-ajax").delay(5).chosen();
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I did $(".chosen-container").width('100%') after setting chosen()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does xajax do?

`delay` only delays animations, it has no effect on any other function.

If you want to delay a function use:

```
setTimeout(function() { $(".chzn-select-ajax").chosen(); }, 500);
```

Comment: I added a link for xajax, let me try this out.

Comment: If I set the delay long enough, this works, but it looks ridiculous...  if the delay is too short, it doesn't work.    Any other ideas?

Comment: Then you need to add a callback in the xajax call that triggers this when done. I didn't realize xajax is asynchronous.

Comment: Hmmm.... ah so that is the issue.  How can I do a callback with that, do you know?

Comment: Looks like: `$objResponse->script("$(this).chosen()");` in PHP (but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(loadControlDuringAjax);
        loadControlDuringAjax();
    });
    function loadControlDuringAjax() {
        $(".chzn-select").chosen(); $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
    }
</script>
```

This works great for me

Hope this will solve your problem